# How to import specific functions, still preserve namespace?

Tags: python, python-2.7

In python, I'd like to import `my_fun()` from `mymodule` but I still wish to call it as `mymodule.my_fun()`. How can I do that?

So far I know only about the following unsatisfying options:

```
import mymodule            # imports all functions :(
mymodule.my_fun()

from mymodule import my_fun 
my_fun()                   # not referred as mymodule.my_fun() :(
```

Something like this would be great:

```
from mymodule import my_fun 
mymodule.my_fun()
```

Comment: There's no smooth way of doing it. You can do `from mymodule import my_fun as momodule__my_fun` if you just want the name to be logical. But it doesn't give you any benefits. Read the possible duplicate.

Comment: Yes, thank you both! My question is an exact duplicate indeed. I voted up the question and the answer where you referred.